# Вычисляемые поля в datatables

Tags: jquery, json, google-api, google-spreadsheet, datatable

Использую плагин datatable для bootstrap, данные передаю посредством json из google spreadsheets. Как мне подсчитать среднее арифметическое значений в поле таблицы? (поле gsx$_d5fpr.$t). И как организовать вычисляемое поле (например нужно вычесть из одного поля другое, причем одно из полей не выводится в таблицу.

```
$('#example2').dataTable( {

    "paging": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 7,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": false,
    "autoWidth": false,    
    "bServerSide":false,
    "bProcessing":true,
    "sAjaxDataProp": "feed.entry",
    "sAjaxSource": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1gTHHSL8OOmGk_EOWjaDEAk5yYAkCWG4KK22I674/1/public/values?alt=json",
    "aoColumns": [  
      { 
        "mDataProp": "gsx$п.$t",

      },
      { "mDataProp": "gsx$компания.$t", "defaultContent": "" },
      { 
        "mDataProp": "gsx$_d5fpr.$t",
        "defaultContent": ""
      },


      { 
        "mDataProp": "", 
        "defaultContent": "",
      },

      { "mDataProp": "gsx$км.$t", "defaultContent": ""  },
      { "mDataProp": "gsx$товар.$t", "defaultContent": "" }
    ]
  });
});
```

Comment: И есть еще проблема. Заголовок поля gsx$_d5fpr.$t  в spreadsheet таблице содержит дату (например 20.08.16), но при преобразовании в json формат получаю случайно сгенерированное название "_d5fpr".  (я так понимаю название поля не может быть числовым либо датой)

Как мне все таки извлечь исходное значение заголовка поля? именно дату?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никто не мешает вычислить среднее арифметическое значение не средствами datatables а например просто распарсить json который тебе приходит, поработать с ним как с обычным javascript массивом/коллекцией объектов. Если нужно из одной колонки вычесть другую - которой нет, опять же можно все сделать через массив. Если уж очень неймется можешь пройтись по ячейкам datatables и вычислить что нибудь как то так:
Назначь для облегчения жизни классам нужным колонкам(например так):

```
       var table = jQuery('#example2').DataTable({
        "columns": [
                    null, {className: "retail-price usd bl"}, 
    {className: "usd bl"}, null, {className: "weight"}}
                ],
        });
        table.cells(".weight").every( function (rowIdx) {
                        var weight = this.data();
                        var weigthValue = parseFloat(weight)-yourCustomValue;
                        //если нужно изменить значение в этом столбике
                        this.data(weigthValue);  
                        //если нужны более сложные вычисления создай 
    //промежуточный массивы и заполни их как то так в цикле 
   //weigthValues[rowIdx] = weigthValue; Потом произведи вычисления 
    //и пройдись по нужно колонке также как по колонке с классом weigth 
    //и подмени что нужно.
                }); 
        //и в конце не забудь сделать перерисовку таблицы
        table.draw();
```

Но это способ как по мне не самый лучший. А вдруг с тебя попросят ajax использовать в datatables, чтобы ускорить работу, будет много боли).